# C++ md5 not matching vb.net md5

Tags: c++, md5

the string is found in a text file testx.txt
the string is Nw[v|YK it contains utf8 characters i believe

```
ifstream infile("testx.txt");

  if (infile.good())
  {
    string sLine;
    getline(infile, sLine);
char* cx = const_cast<char*>(sLine.c_str());
    string a2 = md5.digestString(cx);
    cout << a2 << endl;
  }
```

i have been doing exactly as my vb.net code and reading it as a string then trying to md5 it ... is it because its utf8? what do i do to read it as a string and get the proper md5?

vb.net md5 code

```vb
Public Function GetIRC7PWD(source As String)
        Dim md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
        Dim data As Byte() = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source))
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
        Next i
        Return sBuilder.ToString()

    End Function

End Module
```

text file can be found @ https://tha-row.net/testx.txt

```vb
 Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("d:\\testx.txt")
        Dim line As String = lines(0)
        Dim a1 As String = GetIRC7PWD(line)
```

a1 returns the proper hash of 3be255619a53ec2af553e0cae9606a9a

now i have a md5 code for c++

Comment: I assume you use the exact same file for both programs? Are you using different salts in the two programs? What is your VB.net code doing? Where is the C++ MD5 implementation coming from?

Comment: im using a md5 code i found on stackoverflow ....

Comment: if i do md5.digestString("moo");
i get the same value  that i get in my vb.net md5

but if i try to get the same md5 hash from the text file its different

Comment: System.String in vb.net is documented to use UTF-16 internally. md5 in vb.net counts another byte stream.

Comment: http://tha-row.net/testx.txt

is the text file

Comment: 3be255619a53ec2af553e0cae9606a9a is what i get returned from vb.net code

Comment: c++ is returning the wrong md5 hash 721e85a79c457a368ea9219944307401

Comment: If you change both your C++ and VB.net code to read the file in binary mode, as a stream of *bytes*, what result do you get then?

Comment: Please show a [mre] including your vb code, my guess would be that you are including the line endings in your vb hash which you aren't in c++

Comment: ````Public Function GetIRC7PWD(source As String)
        Dim md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
        Dim data As Byte() = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source))
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
        Next i
        Return sBuilder.ToString()

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to improve it. And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains UTF-8 BOM, the three bytes in the beginning: 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF.

VB.Net detects the BOM in the file, the file encoding and dropps that three bytes off.

C++ istream reads raw bytes, `getline` returns the first string on that three bytes longer. Thus you get another MD5 sum.

Try

```
if (a2.substr(0, 3) == "\xEF\xBB\xBF")
   a2.erase(0, 3);
```

Comment: thanks so how do i get it to read without the three bytes

Comment: @ravi_elite you need to read the file as binary. Why hash the file as string? `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` is wrong because the file isn't in UTF-16. You must use the correct encoding. There's no such thing as plain text files. Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)